# Кэширование изображений, отдаваемых php

Tags: php, кэширование

Такая ситуация: у меня есть `php` скрипт, который проверяет авторизирован пользователь или нет и **отдает** изображения, хранящиеся на этом сервере.

Так, например, при запросе на `localhost/image.php?image=photo.jpg` браузер отдаст изображение `photo.jpg` (Не-не, уязвимости типа `File Inclusion` там нет:), не надо писать об этом). Но сейчас появилась необходимость кэшировать на короткое время отдаваемые изображения этим скриптом. Я добавил заголовок `Expires` с временем кэширования на 2 минуты вот так: `header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 60*2) . " GMT");`, `Cache-Control` у меня по умолчанию стоит `public`.

Но... браузер по-прежнему делает запрос к серверу для получения изображения, как бы игнорируя вышеприведенные заголовки. А мне нужно, чтобы браузер **НЕ** делал запросы к серверу, а вытаскивал изображение из кэша.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так... Заранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать прописать настройки сервера

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ image.php?image=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

А вообще можно попробовать условия авторизации поставить и просто не обращаться к скрипту.